# C++ static const members overriding

Tags: c++, static-members

Consider the following.

```
struct A {
    static const int X = 1;
    static void printX() {std::cout << "X " << X << std::endl; };
};

struct B: public A {
    static const int X = 2;
};

int main(argc argv){
    B b;
    b.printX();
}
```

How to force the `b.printX()` to print value 2?
Both - constant and method - MUST be static. And therefore, virtual methods are not suitable.

For anyone who thinks they know my task better than me and wants to see me rethinking it, I'll explain the goal of my efforts :)
Just imagine class which has behaviour based on set of static constants. The simplest way to implement child class with different set of constants and therefore with different behaviour is derivation of class from previous one with specific set of constant values. It is possible to solve that task using virtual functions. Of cause possible, no question. But this solution will be not very pure in sense of accordance to a theory of modeled entities. Usage of virtual methods in this case will be more a trick than correct implementation.
For example, IR channels have different timing of pulse durations and package structure. It is convenient to define set of child classes (different IR channel implementations) with a specific set of constant values. That values are static because they are common for every object of class and const because they are needed at compile time only. And because internal implementations of base and child classes are slightly different the best relationship between of them are `super class - child class`.
Is it rationale for my original question now?

Comment: It is not possible. You want dynamic dispatching without using `virtual`, and it is contradictory (unless you re-implement your object system by hand).

Comment: C'mon, to force `b.printX()` to print 2 one just needs to replace `X` with 2 in `printX()` definition ;-)

Comment: No I do not want to use dynamic dispatching. I want to use static members everriding.

Comment: In addition to @BasileStarynkevitch's comment, consider this: How would A know about the contents of B? If you said "make B a friend of A," well, that's just bad design, and A would still have to refer to X as B::X to get B's value for X. (The fact that you can refer to A::X as X is just a convenience.)

Comment: @jpm, what's the purpose of friendship between exhibitionst `struct`s?

Comment: Sorry, missed that they were structs. It's still bad design.

Comment: @jpm: A does not neet to know about B anything. If method printX is inherited then theoretically it is able to use local static constant X. Why not?

Comment: Inside of A, X means A::X. Even if you refer to printX by the alias b.printX(), you're really calling A::printX(), which only knows about A::X.

Comment: @jpm: thx a lot for your explanation how it is, but I need to know hot do what I need.

Comment: Maybe an enum with name X in both struct A and B would also be sufficient?!  (enum { X = 1 };)

Comment: @Mario: an enum is not sufficient at least because the end goal of this question is usage of static const struct instead of simple type constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make the value of X a template parameter:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int XValue=1>
struct A {
        static const int X = XValue;
        static void printX() {std::cout << "X " << X << std::endl; };
};

template<int XValue=2>
struct B: public A<XValue> {
};

struct C: public B<3> {
};

int main(int, char**){
        B<> b;
        b.printX();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You are going to need a template, and to change the inheritance to use the template, as you will see. The trick is to make it work whether the derived class has an X to overshadow the base-class X or not.

```
template<class C>
struct A {
    static const int X = 1;
    template<typename T>
    static int getX(decltype(T::X)*) 
        { return T::X; }
    template<typename T>
    static void getX(...)
        { return X; }
    static void printX()
        { std::cout << "X " << getX<C>(0) << std::endl; }
};

struct B: public A<B> {
    static const int X = 2;
};

struct B2: public A<B2> {
    // No X
};

int main(){
    B b;
    b.printX(); // Prints X 2
    B2 b2;
    b2.printX(); // Prints X 1
}
```

Comment: Warmer! But cumbersome a little bit. And BTW, why did you use decltype(T::X) with asterisk? Why pointer, not value?

Comment: +1 Nice solution! (@OlegG the pointer is necessary so the dummy argument `0` works regardless of the type of `X`)

Comment: Nice solution but I still think that the design is bad and Oleg needs to sit down and either rethink it or tell us what he's actually trying to do.

Comment: @JiveDadson: generally speaking, usage of templates in this task is not very good solution because of inheritance necessity. Your idea to use decltype() is nice but it will better to invent some analogue of this for a current type value. Then we'll just write cout << this::X << endl and that was all I need. The question is how to invent that this?

Comment: @OlegG My first try at it attempted to define a type D so you could write D::X in the base-class, but the compiler I have (VC++ 2012) rejected it. I think I am right and it is wrong, but I do not like to post answers that do not compile.  I have changed the code so it uses getX<C>(0), which is not as pretty as D::X, but it does work.

Comment: @OlegG - You are stuck with using templates, because C++ has no other mechanism for doing polymorphic stuff at compile-time.

Comment: @JiveDadson: yes, it seems you're right and I've touch to a limit of C++ abilities. It seems, in that case no appropriate alternatives for runtime polymorphism. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 4):

By definition, anything you do with static members will be "overshadowing", not "overriding". You could reimplement "printX()" in "B", but you would not really be overriding the behavior; because this would use overshadowing, the behavior would depend entirely on the compile-time, not runtime, type.

Comment: I think OP might be confused RE the distinction due to the allowance of calling a class's static on an instance of that class.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `static` and `template`, I would just use regular constant attributes and constructors.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A(const char* fn, const int X) : filename(fn), X(X) {};
    void print() { std::cout << "X = " << X << ", FN = " << filename << std::endl; };

  protected:
    const char* filename;
    const int X;
};

struct B : public A {
    B() : A("data.dat", 5) {};
};

int main(int, char **) {
    B b;
    b.print();
}
```

Functionally, it does exactly what you want. Output:

```
X = 5, FN = data.dat
```

— It's now the compiler's job to optimize those constants. And if you are not intending to use thousands of objects `B`, it's probably not worth worrying about making those constants `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using templates?

```cpp
constexpr int nfo[]{ 0, 1, 2, 3 };

template <int N>
class Haha {
public:
        const static int BOOM = nfo[ N ];
};
int main() {
        std::cout << Haha<2>::BOOM << std::endl; // 2
}
```

Comment: See accepted answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't.

Slightly longer, more complex answer: Well, maybe you can. With *templates*!

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> struct A 
{
    static const int X = 1;

    static void printX() 
    { 
        std::cout << "X=" << T::X << std::endl; 
    }
};

struct B : public A<B> 
{
    static const int X = 2;
};

int main(int, char **)
{
    B b;

    b.printX();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Next step of inheritance (C from B) will kill `printX()`

Comment: Sure, but frankly, if you need to do this at a deeper level, you design sucks and perhaps you should rethink it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll play along... you want to nest this more than one level deep. Fine.

```
#include <iostream>

template <int XX> struct T
{
    static const int X = XX;

    static void printX()
    {
        std::cout << "X=" << X << std::endl;
    }   
};

struct AA 
{
    static const int X = 1;

    /* all other members go here */
};

struct A : public AA, public T<AA::X>
{
    /* empty - put stuff in AA instead */
};

struct BB : public AA
{
    static const int X = 2;
};

struct B : public BB, public T<BB::X>
{
};

struct CC : public BB
{
    static const int X = 3;
};

struct C : public CC, public T<CC::X>
{
};

struct DD : public CC
{
    static const int X = 4;
};

struct D : public DD, public T<DD::X>
{
};

int main(int, char **)
{
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    D d;

    a.printX();
    b.printX();
    c.printX();
    d.printX();

    return 0;
}
```

You could even skip the `static const int X = ...;` in every class, and just do `public T<1>`, `public T<2>` etc as necessary.

Comment: Of course, with this design you cannot cast a B to an A, since they don't derive directly from each other. But hey... you win some, you lose some.

Comment: The direct derivation B from A is necessary.

Comment: Is it now? Oops... *rolls eyes*

Comment: sorry, I didn't analyze the new solution deeply because it looks very cumbersome and due to this inappropriate. There mus be a simpler solution